# Samba share guest read only,write after authentication

Tags: samba, sharing

I'm currently trying to setup my home samba server so that guests can read only and not write/delete

i have it set like this and i can both read and write

```
[share]
comment = Ubuntu Share
path = /your/samba/share
browsable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = no
write list = user
create mask = 0755
```

if i edit read only to yes i can no longer write and i don't get a promt for user/passwd i only ge permission denied error

i'm using ubuntu server and accessing the share from win 10 machine and android devices

PLS help
btw i'm still new to linux !

Answer (score 1):

Despite the "write list" specification windows will see that as a public share and not get prompted for credentials.

A couple of options:

[1] Don't allow anonymous public access to the share. Set guest ok to No:

```
[share]
comment = Ubuntu Share
path = /your/samba/share
browsable = yes
guest ok = no
read only = yes
write list = user
create mask = 0755
```

Now everyone that accesses that share must pass credentials but only one user can write. This forces you to create a dummy guest user - like smbuser for example - with a simple dummy samba password - like smbuserpw for example - for all your guest users to pass to the server.

[2] Create 2 shares - one guest accessible read only:

```
[share-Public]
comment = Ubuntu Share
path = /your/samba/share
browsable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = yes
```

And one write accessible only to those who have the right credentials:

```
[share-Private]
comment = Ubuntu Share
path = /your/samba/share
browsable = yes
guest ok = no
read only = no
valid users = user
create mask = 0755
```

Comment: It works TY very much!